# Namespacing in JSON

Tags: java, json, xml, namespaces

I have a json structure like this.

```
{
    "person": [{
            "fname": "afname",
            "lname": "alname"
        },
        {
            "fname": "bfname",
            "lname": "blname"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now is there an efficient way to introduce a namespace within this json for example the `fname` and `lname` properties can be used in a different context inside the same json but is qualified with a namespace so can be distinguished more efficiently.

Comment: What's your measure of "efficiency"?

Comment: From the duplicate link, be sure not to miss the comment which links to [*Thinking about Namespaces in JSON*](https://www.mnot.net/blog/2011/10/12/thinking_about_namespaces_in_json) by Mark Nottingham.

Comment: See also [*Do Not Emulate XML Namespaces in JSON*](http://lists.xml.org/archives/xml-dev/201506/msg00024.html) by Roger Costello.